# How do I save files to device storage when the app is installed?

Tags: android, kotlin

is there a way to write all the images in the drawables to the device storage when the app is installed? I don’t want to have to check everytime the main activity is created

Comment: Of course. Just copy them at first start of your app. And of course you have to check at every start if they are already copied.

Comment: But... Why would you copy them to the file system? If you need a file you can just load it from drawables.

Comment: That’s just the way it has been specified to do it ‍♂️

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to write all the images in the drawables to the device storage when the app is installed?

No. Apps do not get control when they are installed, for security reasons.